# Python Error: IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I am getting the following error from the command prompt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\read_csv.py", line 14, in <module>
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Section 3")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1464, in to_ex
cel
startrow=startrow, startcol=startcol)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1517, in  write_cells
for cell in cells:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py", line 1893, in get_formatted_cells
self._format_body()):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py", line 1864, in _format_hierarchical_rows
fill_value=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1515, in take
na_value=self._na_value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1534, in _assert_take_fillable
taken = values.take(indices)
IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.
Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of
<xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x024BF5B0>> ignored
```

What I'm trying to do is take data from 3 different CSV files and write each to a respective tab on an Excel file I saved. Current code below:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_csv("File1.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("File2.csv")
df3=pd.read_csv("File3.csv")

# Creates a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Excel File", engine="xlsxwriter")

# Convert data frames to an XlsxWriter Excel Object
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Section 1")
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Section 2")
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Section 3")

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: shot in the dark: have you tried `writer.close()` after the save?

Comment: That was my first thought. Should have included that code, but it still spits out the same error.I'll edit my post to include it.

Comment: please post full stacktrace.

Comment: Added the whole error

Comment: The real error is rather `IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.`

Comment: Is that coming from there being blank columns in the CSV? If I comment out the df3 stuff it runs like I would want

Comment: could be, yes. Try removing them.

Comment: It is working. It looks like it overwrote a file I created to house the data. I had a chart tab that basically summarizes the data. I'm guessing that's because I'm writing to a file and not appending to a file?